# Can we reopen question " Shareholder bullies and doesn't like me. How to deal with this?"

Tags: discussion

[Shareholder bullies and doesn't like me. How to deal with this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84952/shareholder-bullies-and-doesnt-like-me-how-to-deal-with-this)

This has been edited several times and is asking how to address behavior, which IMO, is a goal we can address, as opposed to the close reason.

Comment: Voted to reopen, there certainly seems to be an addressable goal here, even if it is a bit lost in the lengthy paragraph of complaints about Jack's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The question still boils down to:  My situation sucks doesn't it. I think it is too broad to deal with here in any form.  There is no answer to how can i effectively deal with this.

We could answer something much more focused like:

> I would like to set up a meeting with Jack to address these issues in
>   [detailed specific way].  How should I go about preparing for this
>   meeting?

.